# Should one use the base package or the haskell2010 package?

Tags: cabal

In my first attempt at using cabal I ran into something that confuses me.

I have a Haskell file that starts with

```
import Data.List(nub,(\\), minimumBy)
import Data.Array
import Data.Ord(Ordering(..))
```

This compiles fine with command-line ghc.

But I thought I would use cabal, since I'm editing with IntelliJ and it uses cabal as a build tool.  The cabal file that gets produced by IntelliJ (or cabal, or some combination) contains the line

```
build-depends:   base
```

And I get the error that it can't find `Data.Array`

So I change the build-depends line to

```
build-depends:   base, haskell2010
```

And I get an error that `Prelude` was found in multiple packages.

So I try

```
build-depends:   haskell2010
```

And I get an error that `Data.Ord` can't be found.

Eventually I figured out that I could use

```
build-depends:   base, array
```

or I could use just

```
build-depends: haskell2010
```

and omit the import of `Data.Ord`.

But all this made me wonder why there is a `base` package as well as a `haskell2010` package? What makes sense to me is to start with the modules defined in the language standard (which is what I think `haskell2010` represents) and then add on nonstandard libraries as needed.  Is `base` a subset of `haskell2010`?  I also noticed that hoogle tends to steer me toward `base` and away from `haskell2010`.

In short what is the relationship between the `base` and `haskell2010` packages? And how should one decide which to use to get the Prelude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally one uses the `base` package. The only usage of `Haskell2010` is if you want to pin yourself to a particular standard for a reference implementation (which is rare). The latter package makes especially less sense lately, as it was a compat-layer over base, and certain changes in base couldn't be fully papered over.

So the recommended way is certainly:

```
build-depends:   base, array
```